# Actualizar datos automáticamente

Tags: angularjs

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
 <input type="range" ng-init="overral=0" ng-model="overral"/> {{overral}}

 <input ng-model="value1" type="number" ng-init="value1=10" />
 <input ng-model="age1" type="number" ng-init="age1=30" />
 <input ng-model="postal1" type="number" ng-init="postal1=25" />
```

Si actualizo "overral" a 40:

```
value1 = valu21*40;
age1= age1*40;
postal1= postal1*40;
```

o 
Si actualizo "overral" a 80:

```
value1 = valu21*80;
age1= age1*80;
postal1= postal1*80;
```

pero necesito que se actulice automaticamente en el input el valor, sin pasar por un controlador

Comment: ¿Porqué quieres hacerlo sin ngChange?

Comment: imagiante que en vez de 3 inputs, tengo 100 y los nombres de ng-model son totalmente diferentes

Comment: Intenta explicar tu problema con un caso que te ha pasado para poder ayudarte.

Comment: he editado mi pregunta para que este un poco mas claro